# How does this C++ code let me call a function with a wrong number of arguments?

Tags: c++, class

code.h

```
char* f(int ar1, int arg2, int arg3, char** arg4= NULL);
```

code.cpp

```
 char* f(int ar1, int arg2, int arg3, char** arg4) {
          ...
}
```

other_code.cpp

```
char* r= f(1,2,3);
```

other_cod.cpp calls this function f with 3 args, but the function has 4 args in the definition. There is no other function with the name f. How can this calling succeed?

Comment: do you understand what [default args](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Argument arg4 is not necessary, if not given specifically the default value of NULL will be used.

More info can be found here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments

Answer (score 0):

The compiler converts this call

```
char* r= f(1,2,3);
```

to

```
char* r= f(1,2,3, NULL);
```

because the declaration specifies a default value for the last parameter.

You can make any number of parameters optional by providing default values for them, starting with the last one and going back. For example, if you do this

```
char* f(int ar1 = 1, int arg2 = 2, int arg3 = 3, char** arg4= NULL);
```

you can call `f` with any number of parameters from zero to four, and C++ would substitute default values for all formal parameters lacking a corresponding argument expression.